# filter dataframe value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, filtering

Hi I was trying to extract only the no's from a columns in my df with this code:

```
(df['hello']=='No')
```

But it changes the values from the df and put it like a boolean values, I just want to value_count in that column the No's, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like count

```
(df['hello']=='No').sum()
```

More like `value_counts`

```
df['hello'].value_counts().loc['No']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are using pandas.DataFrame, if you want to get the subset of `df` rows with `'hello'` column value `'No'`, use:

```
df[df['hello']=='No']
```

If you only want the column `'hello'`:

```
df['hello'][df['hello']=='No']
```

Comment: If I only want the column 'hello' I have to select it after and sabe the subset in a df2 = df[df['hello']=='No'] right?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually query a DataFrame with .value_counts(). This will return an integer of how many times the query is True.

```py
print(df['hello'].value_counts()['No'])
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
print(df['hello'].value_counts())
```